# Process is not defined Svelte/Vite (using node-imap)

Tags: node.js, npm, svelte

I am trying to use the library [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) in my SvelteKit/Vite application. I import the library with   `import * as Imap from "imap";`. When I try running my application, I get the following error:

```
process is not defined
ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at node_modules/.pnpm/utf7@1.0.2/node_modules/utf7/utf7.js (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/imap.js?v=e5efcf87:944:20)
    at __require (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-OL3AADLO.js?v=e5efcf87:9:50)
    at node_modules/.pnpm/imap@0.8.19/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/imap.js?v=e5efcf87:5022:16)
    at __require (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-OL3AADLO.js?v=e5efcf87:9:50)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/imap.js?v=e5efcf87:6690:20
```

The problem seems to be that Vite/Svelte does not support `process`, rather using `import.meta.env` for environment variables. How can I get the library working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to make sure the code only runs on the server, as the client will not have access to process.

[Endpoints](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#endpoints) will run only on the server while [`load`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/loading) will run both on client and server.

E.g. this endpoint code would be valid:

```js
import type { RequestHandler } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const get: RequestHandler = () => {
    return {
        body: { env: process.env }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am making a desktop app, so SSR is disabled, and I only have the client. Is it possible to get around this limitation somehow?

Comment: Making a desktop application does not preclude SSR. Depends on what you are using to build the desktop application. In some frameworks, like Electron, you can expose Node APIs, packages or variables to the client code. For specifics you should check the respective documentation or search StackOverflow.